# How to play background push notification sound

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification

I'm working on an app in which, upon receiving a push notification while in the background, should play a continuous sound until the app is opened.

Also, if the app is opened by clicking on the app icon, it should load push data.

How can I do this?

Comment: did you ever solve this?

Comment: @vikzilla.. in push if we change the sound:Default to other file sound file name which exist in our app then it will pay that sound and that file should be .wav formate and max approx length is 20 sec of that sound file the name of that file you have to pass in sound tag,more then that length it will not pay sound it will pay default sound of push..you can not play continues sound..